# Autofit.rowheight depending on text(string) in each cell of that row

Tags: vba, excel

Bear in mind:

1. Different column.width,
2. each cell has different string(length)
3. All Text must appear!

Its not easy because you can't tell how much space each line has? 
Not cut the biggest cell (like, when I do that manually sometimes the last line is cut off)
(like autofit, because autofit just looks at one cell(.select) not all cells in that row, if there is another cell with more content it get's cut off)

If someone has a hint for me, would be awesome!

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub dynamicRowFit() 'start of the sub
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aRng As Range 'maybe we just need one range?
    Dim bRng As Range
    Dim defRow As Integer
    Dim defColmn As Integer

    Set defRow = 'enter the row to start(as Integer)
    Set defColmn = 'enter the Column to start (as Integer)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'helps to prevent screenfreezes
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'defines window
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set aRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(defRow, defCulmn), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

'this is a defined loop with defined height, I need a dynamic solution:

    For Each bRng In aRng
        If Len(bRng) <= 90 Then 'when lengh of string is smallerOrequal to 90
            bRng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15
        Else
            bRng.EntireRow.AutoFit
        End If
    Next bRng

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'till all cells emty
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True'Enables the update of screen
End Sub 'end of sub
```

So, it also depends on the .size(type size(I'll have just one 11) and font (each font can be different in size, means space needed for each character).
I did my best to define my question, tags, etc. as good as possible ;-)

Comment: Where do you give value to `defRow` and `defCulmn`?

Comment: We need to set the values in the beginning, the user must define that. (starting-point)

Comment: I agree - where in your code does your user define that? You have no place for it yet?

Comment: I will add that in the code, one sec ;)

Comment: I'm failing to see why you can't use `.AutoFit` for all your rows?

Comment: The problem is, that .AutoFit also changes the width of the columns, I just want to autofit the .rowheight maybe we can work around by using the "slicer"Object or "Wrap" (I am using here excel2010)

Comment: Maybe I don't get, how .AutoFit works?

Comment: First, I want to be dead certain, that the content of that cell is shown and doesen't cut of the last line, if printed. Second, I want to optimise the area a cell needs to save costs for printed pages. Third, I don't want to change the width of that cell.